# Difficulty expanding a term.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am required to expand the following terms up to and including $x^2$:

$$(1+x)(1-x)^9$$

I have reached the expression,

$$(1-x+36x^2)(1+x)$$

I am however unable to multiply $(1+x)$ into the expression to the left and reach the expected term of $1-8x+27x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-x)^9=1-\mathbf9x+36x^2-\dots$$
You forgot a binomial coefficient. Now try doing the multiplication as you wanted to.

Comment: That is actually what confuses me on how to fuse correctly these two terms otherwise thanks for pointing out the error btw.

Comment: It's a simple schoolboy's error. The leading term is actually multiplied by a binomial coefficient of 1.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further

Comment: You've got $1, -x, +x^2$ and so on, right? You now need to consider the row of Pascal's triangle that begins 1, 9, 36, ... and multiply term-by-term. Since the first multiplier is 1, it doesn't show up when you write it down.

Comment: is it possible for you to elaborate slightly further please

Comment: Er, what do you want elaborated? You need to be _very careful_ with your binomial coefficients when you're doing expansions by hand.

Comment: So basically you need to expand both terms then multiply the coefficient of corresponding x to power of n values

Comment: You multiply the 1 and the -x together, as you've done, and then you need to multiply by the binomial coefficient. That is what I said.

Comment: Now you can accept and upvote answers on your questions. I upvoted this question, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the $(1-x)^9$ term with binomial expansion.

$$(1+x)(1-x)^9=(1+x)(1-9x+{9\choose2}x^2+\ldots)$$

Group up $x^2$ terms.